# Capturing/scraping book genre information from google

Tags: automation, web-scraping, screen-scraping, google-search

When I search for a book on google (search query: book title + genre e.g. of 'mice and men genre') I get the book genre(s) in a box which is above the search results. Sometimes there are multiple genres and sometimes just the one.

How can I capture this data?

I have a large list of books which I need the Genre information for. Are there any automated methods to gather this data? or alternative sources?